# How do i make 1 button play random sounds each time i press the button using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, random

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
MediaPlayer mp; 
ImageButton soundbutton;
```

//This is sounds being added

```
int[] sounds ={R.raw.yeet1, R.raw.yeet2, R.raw.yeet3, R.raw.yeet4, R.raw.yeet5, R.raw.yeet6, R.raw.yeet7, R.raw.yeet8, R.raw.yeet9, R.raw.yeet10, R.raw.yeet11, R.raw.yeet12, R.raw.yeet13}; 
Random r = new Random(); 
int Low = 0; 
int High= 13; 
int rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low; 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

//creating the Mediaplayer

```
    soundbutton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button_view); 
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]); 
    soundbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            try { 
                if (mp.isPlaying()) { 
                    mp.stop(); 
                    mp.release(); 
                    rndm = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low; 
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[rndm]); 
                } 
                mp.start(); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        }
```

This code wont run and i'm not sure whats causing it thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `mp` is not playing the `if` block is not executed.  
Change to this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
        rndm = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[rndm]);
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It says casting "this.findViewById(R.id.button_view)" to "Imagebutton" is redundant.

Comment: remove `(ImageButton)`

Comment: @SNGACDLoqi is there a problem?

Comment: Yeah the build was successful but my app stops working, im looking in the logcat it says: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton

Comment: Then it's a Button not ImageButton. Change ImageButton soundbutton; to `Button soundbutton;`